# Insert some posts in a loop - wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I wrote a plugin, which reads csv files and create new products. The plugin works when I create only one product but when I add  `while`  in `Insert()` the plugin doesn't work. I want to create all products first off. Maybe it's something related to the add_action... Please help.

```
define( 'PLUGIN_DIR', dirname(__FILE__).'/' );

function CreateProduct($line) {    
    $data = explode('";"', $line);  
    define(POST_NAME, $data[2]);
    define(cena_netto_pw, $data[5]);

    $post = get_page_by_title( POST_NAME, 'OBJECT', 'product'  );
    $product_ID = $post->ID;
    $post_data = get_post($product_ID);

    function hbt_create_post() {
        $my_post = array(
          'post_title'    => POST_NAME,
          'post_content'  => '',
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'post_author'   => 1,
          'post_type'     =>'product'
        );

        $product_ID = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
    }

    if(!isset($post))
        hbt_create_post();
    return $error_obj;
}

function Import() {
    $file = PLUGIN_DIR.'test.csv';
    $open = fopen($file, 'r');
    while (!feof($open)) {

        $line = fgets($open);
        CreateProduct($line);

    }
    fclose($open); 
}

add_action('admin_init', 'Import' ); 

?>
```

While loop code

```
while (!feof($open)) { $line = fgets($open); CreateProduct($line); }
```

This code doesn't work. It works when there is only

```
$line = fgets($open); CreateProduct($line);
```

Comment: show your code with while loop

Comment: It is: 
while (!feof($open)) {
        $line = fgets($open);
        CreateProduct($line);
}
This code doesn't work. It works when there is only
$line = fgets($open);
CreateProduct($line);

Comment: Please test with `txt` file instead of csv. What is the result?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
fgetcsv($open)
```

instead

```
fgets($open)
```